# How to run a function all the time continuously until the activity is in foreground?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having a function in my code.And I want this function to run after every 2 minute if the activity is in the foreground and stop it when it is in the background.
Suppose I have a function x() just toasting "Hello World".
I want to run this function after every two minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make handler like

```
           Runnable r2=new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Your Toast
                h2.postDelayed(r2,20000);   
                }
            };

            Handler h2=new Handler();
```

Call this handler in activity `onResume()`

```
h2.postDelayed(r2,20000);
```

and stop handler in activity `onPause()`

```
h2.removeCallbacks(r2);
```

Comment: where to put this runnable? in oncreate?

Comment: @user3788866 Just create runnable on your activity class.

Comment: can i call a function inside run?

Comment: I f I want this task to be run in a service in background I meant runing in the background if an activity comes in foreground.It shouldn't stop

Comment: @user3788866 If you run this task in Service in background then you'll able to apply all the life cycle of service. and you doesn't care about activity.